# Setting Items For Modal ViewController Toolbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a ViewController which I'm using a modal transition for. It has a toolbar and I've added five items (including space) in interface builder. I'm trying to set the buttons from code, so when the table view in this modal ViewController is being edited, show a 'lock' button, when it's not editing, show an 'unlock' button.

Despite my attempts, the buttons aren't changing.

I've tried (updated 13th Jan):

```
[self setToolbarItems:...animated:true]; // failed
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:... animated:true]; // also failed, though self.navigationItem is not null
[self.parentViewController setToolbarItems:... animated:true];
[self.navigationController setToolbarItems:... animated:true];
[self.tabBarController setToolbarItems:... animated:true];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:... animated:true];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:
```

All of which failed.

This ViewController is shown from another VC (non modal), which is pushed onto a NavigationController.

Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Of which class is the subclass of your ViewController?

Comment: It's a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than changing the buttons in the toolbar, I eventually just added a button in Interface Builder and changed the background image:

```
btnLock.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lock_open_white_30.png"];
```

If you really did need to change the buttons, you'd probably need to create all the buttons and expose them on your ViewController, the use `setHidden` to hide/show them.